# Why hibernate keeps returning me 0 as the value from dtb?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got table in `MySQL database` with this structure:

[image]

And hibernate **mapping for object `PatientDAO` here:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="cz.cvut.fit.genepi.models.PatientDAO" table="patient">
        <id name="_id" type="int">
            <column name="id" precision="6" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="_nin" type="long">
            <column name="nin" length="20" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="_birthday" type="date">
            <column name="birthday" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="_gender" type="string">
            <column name="gender" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="_doctor_id" type="int">
            <column name="doctor_id" precision="6" scale="0" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="_deleted" type="int">
            <column name="deleted" precision="1" scale="0" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="_checked" type="int">
            <column name="checked" precision="1" scale="0" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="_contact_id" type="int">
            <column name="contact_id" precision="6" scale="0" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="_comment_id" type="int">
            <column name="comment_id" precision="6" scale="0" not-null="false" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But when I'm trying to get some sample data from dtb and print them out, I get only `0`. This happens for any possible property of `Patient DAO`. And for any `id` of searched patient.
I'm sure, that patient with `id==0` is contained in that table.

**`findByID` function:**

```
public T findByID(Class<T> myClass, int id) {
        Session hibernateSession = this.getSession();
        T t = null;
        t = (T) hibernateSession.get(myClass, id);
        return t;
    }
```

**part of `PatientDAO` (without setters and getters):**

```
public class PatientDAO implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * generated serialVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8172690860460945951L;

    private int _id;
    private long _nin;
    private Date _birthday;
    private String _gender;
    private int _doctor_id;
    private int _deleted;
    private int _checked;
    public int get_checked() {
        return _checked;
    }
    }
```

My personal tip is that I got there something wrong in my mapping, because for simplier objects it worked well. But I'm quite new to `hibernate`, so I can't figure out, what can be there wrong.. I'd be really glad if someone could help.

Comment: Really, start by respecting the Java naming conventions. An entity and a DAO are very different things. Your fiels should not start with underscores. And the getters should be named getDoctorId() and not get_doctor_id(). This looks like obfuscated code to any Java developer.

Comment: Your mapping document is missing a [temporal designation for your date](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html) field.

Comment: @JBNizet uh? I must admit, that I'm quite new to `hibernate` so maybe I didn't understand well the purpose of `DAO`, neverhteless, I think, that is good convence to name your private properties with `_` on the beginning. And that getters and setters were generated by `Spring Tool Suite`...and I must also admit, that it looks weird..

Comment: Look at all the Java code around you. All the clases of the JDK. Starting fields with an underscore breaks the Java naming conventions. And STS generates getters and setters from the bad names you chose for your fields, which of course also generates bad names for the accessor methods.

Comment: @JBNizet ah ok...correct... I'm still a little bit messing up my code with `C#` convence :) I'll correct it.. thx

Comment: Regarding the DAO. A DAO is an object used to get, find and save entities. It mainly contains methods executing queries and returning entities. An entity is a persistent object. An entity is usually named after what it represents: Order, Customer, Account, Patient, etc. A PatientDAO would thus be a class containing methods used to persist, update and find patients in the database.

Comment: @hd1 Uh I think I don't get it... I had `Date` in my previous table as well, but it worked well. Wouldn't you mind to explain it more and post it as an answer?

Comment: Dworza, it's not an answer, and I linked to the hibernate documentation.

Answer (score 0):

problem was in bad mapping... I actually dind't see, that nin should be `varchar` and I declared it as `long`